# How to get user's groups in xmpp on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp

I hava implemented an iOS client based on xmpp, now I want to implement MUC, but I don't know how to get a list of groups a user is in, also a user gets out of the room every time he/she get offline.

I know there are two ways:

1. Save a user's groups locally and rejoin a room every time this user logs in. But I don't know how to save this, if I use NSUserDefaults, then I can only save a room's JID instead of the room. If so, how can a user rejoin a room when he/she is logged in?The only way I know now to join a room is `[room joinRoomUsingNickname:[stream.myJID bare] history:nil];` This requires a room, not only a room's JID.
2. Get a list of rooms from the server every time a user logs in, but this seems impossible since a user gets kicked out of the room every time he/she get offline.

Pls help, thanks!

Comment: you get any answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save locally the room JID and recreate the room to join thanks to its JID.

Comment: I have tried this, but how to recreate a room ,do I have to recreate a rosterStorage too? Pls give me some example code if it's convenient, thanks!